# How to access previous element not sibling

Tags: jquery

I have the following code structure:

```
<div></div>

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<div></div>

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li id="current"></li>
</ul>
```

Sorry I used HTML in my post and it hid DIV.

I am looking for a `<DIV>` immediately above  the parent `<UL>`.

Comment: Such as, `.parent()` to get the parent `ul` element? your question isn't very clear. A previous element is always going to be a sibling of the current element by definition.

Comment: Do you want the `ul` or the `div`?

Comment: Really? -4 for this questions...

Comment: @santa The downvotes are most likely due to the fact that you have shown no effort to fix the problem yourself, and that originally the question was not very clear. It is better now.

Comment: I've tried prev()... I'm still trying to wrap my mind around .parent().prev() It seems it should select previous <UL>... :)

Comment: For clarification, .prev() gets the previous sibling, meaning the previous element that shares the same direct parent. .parent of course gets the direct parent of the selected element. Therefore, .parent() gets the ul, then .prev gets the previous sibling of the ul, in this case the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either:

```
$('#current').parent() // goes to the closest parent - which is the <ul>
             .prev();  // now, starting at that <ul>
                       // we go to the previous html element which is <div>

//Could also be done:
$('#current').closest('ul')
             .prev();  // or .prev('div') - there's a lot of options
```

Comment: Note however that `.prev('div')` only selects the immediately previous element if and only if it is a div, it will not recursively go through previous elements looking for the first div it finds.

Comment: Yeah I typically try not to use just .prev(), I'll usually use a class let's say .prev('.thisThing') - never know when someone will randomly make a UI change and break everything!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

`.parent().prev()` is what you're looking for i think

---

**Original**

`.parent()` is what you're looking for i think

Comment: your question is unclear that you want the div not the ul.

Comment: Sorry, I used HTML and it became invisible in post...

Answer (score 2):

first use parent() and then prev(). like `$('#current').parent().prev()`

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the "not sibling" requirement.

Comment: I do not need another <LI>. I need <div> above the <UL>

Answer (score 2):

You seem to need

```
$('#current').parent().prev()
```

This selects the `div` just before the `ul` containing `current`.